# How to not spliting specific format with the use of regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Currently I have a list of string like this

```
"banana、xx、tyu、fdg dfgdf、dfgfdgd、dfdfg、dfgdg 、cvbcvb", dfdgd
sdfs. 2te. 459,202'   dfg/ dfg, bvn, bn, wqe。uyo.
yuo, "yuouy、yuoy、jlkj、nmj , tryrt、346,457、gh、325352 、fghfg"
```

When I use this RegEx : `/[^\pL\pN\\]+/u`, the output would be like :

```
 banana xx tyu fdg dfgdf dfgfdgd dfdfg dfgdg cvbcvb dfdgd sdfs 2te 459 202 dfg dfg bvn bn wqe uyo yuo yuouy yuoy jlkj nmj tryrt 346 457 gh 325352 fghfg
```

In this RegEx it will chop all special characters in the string. What do I want is just not to separate the `459,202` and `346,547` .How can I modify the RegEx to make it not remove `,` between characters like `123,124` or `afd,151` ?

The online example:https://www.regex101.com/r/xA7xE8/1

Comment: did you want to match the spaces also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the non-word boundary `\B`. `\B` matches between two non-word characters or two word characters. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
[^\pL\pN\\,]+|\b,\B|\B,\B|\B,\b
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/xA7xE8/2)

Comment: then you need to escape the `\` one more time. so it would be `\\\\,`

Comment: You're not making any sense with that statement; using `~` or `/` as the delimiter makes no difference here.

Comment: `[^\pL\pN\\,]+|\b,\B|\B,\B|\B,\b`

Comment: @Ja͢ck did you able to run `"~[^\pL\pN\\,]+|\B,\B~"` code?

Comment: @user3571945 or you could use `[^\pL\pN\\,]+|(?:\b,\b(*SKIP)(*F)|,)`

Comment: Thanks you very much. You gave me a lot of help